# A question related to the Moving-average processes

Tags: probability-theory, polynomials, stochastic-processes, time-series

This question is related to [MA processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model)

Suppose $(X_t) \sim MA(1)$:
$$X_t = \epsilon_t + \alpha \epsilon_{t-1}, \quad \epsilon_t \overset{iid}{\sim}N(0,\sigma_1).$$
Now let $\eta_t \overset{iid}{\sim}N(0,\sigma_2)$. Define $Z_t := X_t + \eta_t$
\begin{equation}\label{I}\tag{I}
Z_t = X_t + \eta_t = \epsilon_t + \alpha \epsilon_{t-1} + \eta_t 
\end{equation}

It is well  known that $Z_t \sim MA(1)$, i.e.:
\begin{equation}\label{II}\tag{II}
Z_t = \nu_t + \theta\nu_{t-1}
\end{equation}
Is it possible to determine $\nu_t$ and $\theta$ in (\ref{II}) from (\ref{I})?

If not, what can we learn about $\nu_t$ and $\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (I) we have:

$$
\text{Var}(Z_t)=(1+\alpha^2)\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 \\
\gamma(1) = \alpha \, \sigma_{1} \,, \gamma(k) =0 \quad \forall k\ge2
$$

In (II) we have, with $\nu_t \sim \mathcal{N}(o,\sigma_3)$:

$$
\text{Var}(Z_t)=(1+\theta^2)\sigma_3\\
\gamma(1) = \theta \, \sigma_{3} \,, \gamma(k) =0 \quad \forall k\ge2
$$

From the ACF we see that the processes are indeed $\text{MA}(1)$ and equating both the variances and ACF we get a system of equations in the unknowns $\theta$ and $\sigma_3$ which we can solve to get the parameters in terms of the old ones.

$$
\begin{cases}
(1+\theta^2)\sigma_3 = (1+\alpha^2)\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 \\
\theta \, \sigma_{3} = \alpha \, \sigma_{1}
\end{cases}
$$